# Why Elixir + Webpack + Gulp producing different output between developers

Tags: webpack, gulp, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, laravel-elixir

We've had a developer join the team recently and I'm noticing that his builds are creating all different outputs from our source .js files, even if he never made any changes to the source files.

We are building on top of Laravel, utilizing VueJS, building with webpack.  More specifically, our `gulpfile.js` is like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official');

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.webpack('app.js');
  ...
```

My only assumption is that there is a version difference with the compilation tools that he has on his machine.  But I thought `package.json` is supposed keep everything the same between everyone?  I did do a `npm update` recently but even before doing that, we were getting all sorts of diffs.

Here is a sample diff of a resulting js file:

[image]

[image]

Any hints as to what's going on? Where could we look to sync everyone back up?

Comment: Someone is using windows :) At least for the `\r` things.